# Admin consent to give application registered in Tenant A access to Graph in Tenant B

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

My application is registered in `tenant A` and requires the `Microsoft Graph` permission `Invite guest users to the organization`. The application is an API app without a GUI.

To give the application `Graph` access in `Tenant A` I do the following:
1. go to `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=
<My application ID>&prompt=admin_consent`
2. Login with admin credentials for `tenant A`

Done - my `Service Principal` in `tenant A` now has `Invite guest users to the organization` permission

So far so good. Now I want to give the same application access to invite guest users in `tenant B`. How do I do that?

I've tried the same flow as before:
1. go to `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=
<My application ID>&prompt=admin_consent`
2. Login with admin credentials for `tenant B`

This results in the following error message:

> AADSTS50020: User account 'xxx@yyy.com' from identity provider 'yyy.com' does not exist in tenant 'Tenant A' and cannot access the application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

It seems that this action tries to give the application the required permissions in `Tenant A` even though I login with admin credentials from `Tenant B`.

How do I give the application the required permissions in `Tenant B`? Is it possible to use the admin consent flow with a `Service Principal ID` from `Tenant B` instead of the global `Application ID` for my application?

Comment: Have you registered your app as multi-tenant in Azure AD?

Comment: Yes, it’s configured as multi tenant in Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

The admin account I tried to use for consent in `tenant B` had previously been invited as a guest account in `tenant A`. The guest account had since been removed from `tenant A` but it seems some kind of connection still exists somewhere that disrupts the admin consent flow.

When I created a new admin account in `tenant B` and used the new account (with no history at all in `tenant A`) to consent, it worked as expected.